Bitbucket Cloud /2.0/users API: Forge platform failed to process runtime HTTP request
I'm trying to retrieve user details from Bitbucket cloud users API from my Forge app without success.
This is my code snippet:
    const approverDetails = await api.asApp().requestBitbucket(
      route `/2.0/users/${approver.uuid}`
    ).then(response => {
      console.log(
        `approverDetailsResponse: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`
      );
      return response.text();
    })
    .then(text => JSON.parse(text))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

${approver.uuid} is already surrounded by curly braces: {8968xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxe2d7} .
I'm getting the error below:
ERROR   12:52:31.558  98d59cf4-7b36-41b1-abae-aa9447a523bd  PROXY_ERR: Forge platform failed to process runtime HTTP request - 400 - INVALID_TARGET_URL
    at handleProxyResponseErrors (webpack://bitbucket-merge-check/node_modules/@forge/api/out/api/fetch.js:83:1)
    at <anonymous> (webpack://bitbucket-merge-check/node_modules/@forge/api/out/api/fetch.js:28:1)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at Object.run (webpack://bitbucket-merge-check/src/index.js:42:1)
    at async /tmp/forge-tunnel-59258-tGTsvok2wd42/index.cjs:2:583140
    at async process.<anonymous> (/home/sgargel/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/lib/node_modules/@forge/cli/node_modules/@forge/tunnel/out/sandbox/sandbox-runner.js:7:20) {
  status: 400,
  errorCode: 'INVALID_TARGET_URL'
}


Seems that only endpoints labeled with Forge app scopes are available for use from Forge apps. See: https://developer.atlassian.com/platform/forge/apis-reference/fetch-api-product.requestbitbucket/
